# Build CICD with end to end tests for multi repository architecture

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure-devops, continuous-integration, aws-codepipeline

I have a microservice architecture with tens of repositories. It is deployed on AWS.
I have three environments on separate regions : dev, staging, prod.
Code is hosted on VSTS / Azure Devops.

I am forced to use VSTS for hosting code and AWS CodePipeline to deploy.

I have this double CI setup at the moment. I run unit tests in Azure DevOps that triggers AWS Code Pipeline that will deploy the architecture via Cloudformation.

Now I wand to trigger units tests and end to end tests from a Pull Request for each environment.

I have to be able to deploy to run end to end tests but I am not sure what's happenning if tests wont pass with an already deployed non working architecture.

Repositories can be coupled, and I want to be able to trigger several CI and rollback them.

What is the best solution :

1.

- Keep Unit tests in VSTS
- Trigger code pipeline deployment
- Wait for all codepipelines to be executed and successful
- Trigger end to end from VSTS

2.

- Trigger CodePipeline from VSTS
- Run units tests in CodePipeline
- Deploy new architecture
- Wait for all deployment to be executed and successful
- Run e2e tests from CodePipeline
- Wait for all codepipelie to be ready and successfull and send the response to VSTS to make the CI okay.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I'd prefer option 2.

CodePipeline is a great tool to orchestrate the entire workflow.

Additionally as a point of note, when you say trigger CodePipeline you will need to to deploy using S3 most likely. By waiting for it to be successful you will need to monitor the workflow has executed successfully by the API.

Answer (score 1):

Second option seems to be a better choice:

- you have almost all stuff in one place - you don't need to switch between CodePipeline and AzureDevops to see whole picture
- it should be also easier to develop, yes you can use web hooks on AzureDevops to trigger pipelines, but you should be able to achiive better and simpler control staying (mostly) with one vendor

Imagine a case when you for instance need to rollback after end-2-end tests - which approach will support that scenario better?